# Symfony2: Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

## Problem

Hi, I"m working with a friend on a Symfony2 project. He's working on a Windows based computer and I'm on my Mac.
We setup the project and made the database model / entities (code first) on his computer. Now I wanted to start working on it as well so we did a SQL dumb to my localhost. I edited the parameters.yml to match my settings. The project can connect to the server. 
But when I try to open a page where the database is used i get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.bigimage AS bigimage3, t0.smallimage AS smallimage4, t0.info AS info5, t0.city_id AS city_id6 FROM District t0':
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'socialgeogroep6.District' doesn't exist
>   500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
>   1 linked Exception: PDOException »

Just to be clear, the page is running normal on his computer; he gets the data as it should be.

## Question

What can be the problem? I looked in my PHPmyAdmin over and over again and the database is there with all the fields and data... 
(screen: http://gyazo.com/4a0e5f1ee6b1e29d2d277df5fc0d8aac)
I really can't imagine what the problem is.

I hope someone can help us!

Comment: So, to be clear, your browser is connecting to a webserver on your machine which in turn is attempting to connect to an RDBMS on your machine (the same RDBMS to which that phpMyAdmin screenshot relates)?  Please confirm the URL displayed in the browser address bar when you see that error, and the database configuration/connection parameters in your application.

Comment: Yes, the project is running on localhost with MAMP. (on my Mac, he's running XAMP). The database is a local mySQL database.

Comment: What is your MySQL installation's [`lower_case_table_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) setting?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'`.  And on what filesystem are your data files stored?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's likely a case issue. You have the `district` table on your database, but doctrine is asking for the `District` table.

You should configure doctrine to use lower case table name. Refer to the doctrine documentation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#persistent-classes to know how to do so.

Comment: MySQL case sensitivity follows the filesystem... and HFS+ is (usually) case insensitive.

Comment: This did the trick! I read aswell what @eggyal said that it didn't matter on Mac that's why we didn't thought that would be the issue. But it did apparently. Thanks to Venu as well and eggyal for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I just had exactly the same kind of problem because i'm writing code on windows and i need to deploy on linux.

The solution is to add in config.yml the line:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

Comment: It worked for me while trying to configure it from windows to linux (cloud9 configuration). Thank you

Comment: Did not work for me either (symfony 2.7). See @abdiel 's answer, that one works with charm.

Answer (score 2):

This work for my in symfony 2.7. Just put in config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

Answer (score 1):

Table name case issue

```
socialgeogroep6.District
```

It should be `socialgeogroep6.district` as per the screenshot. Check the Entity annotation.

Comment: MySQL case sensitivity follows the filesystem... and HFS+ is (usually) case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution: Before reading this solution. **This is strictly a solution for those who are trying to set up the framework.**

I think since you are just starting to try out, what you could do is, drop database and then start everything afresh.

```
 - mysql -uroot -proot
 - show databases;
 - drop database <dbname>;
```

Then, recreate the tables.

```
 - app/console doctrine:database:create 
 - app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

**A word of caution it might be a very BAD idea to do this in production environment if you have already created your controllers and data is already populated.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Orm, you can set up it like this

District.orm.yml

```
Project\Bundle\DuterteBundle\Entity\Vp:
  type: entity
  table: district//note the lowercase
  repositoryClass: Project\Bundle\DuterteBundle\Repository\VpRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

May be missed to add singular table name object.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mapping extends Model
{


     protected $table = 'mapping';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'mapping', 'name'
    ];
}
```