# Table 'table' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I am having a problem with a MySQL connection. The connection changes according to the user. When I connect with a DB, it works, but if I try to connect with another IP, I get the error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT codigo_equipo, ti.codigoTipoIncidencia as tipo_de_incidencia, count(codigo_equipo) as cuenta FROM
AYTOGRANADA_BD.incidencias_resumen a INNER JOIN nmgi_gestion.subtipos_incidencia st ON st.idSubtipoIncidencia = a.idSubtipoIncidencia
INNER JOIN nmgi_gestion.tipos_incidencia ti ON ti.idTipoIncidencia = st.idTipoIncidencia
where fecha_inspeccion>='2015-06-14' and fecha_inspeccion<'2015-06-15' group by codigo_equipo':

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'AYTOGRANADA_BD.incidencias_resumen' doesn't exist
```

The structure of the database is the same, and if I make this query from phpmyadmin Server, it says "there " , I return it without a problem.
Can the problem be MySQL permissions?

Thanks

Code to connect:

```
$params['host'] = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
$params['dbname'] = "AYTOGRANADA_BD";
$params['user'] = "root";
$params['password'] = "XXXX";
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380154/symfony2-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146)

Comment: Might be due case sensitivity of table name.

Comment: When i copy this query in my phpmyadmin, it's execute successfull. Help me please !

Answer (score 0):

I think your root user only have local access.

Try locally to execute:

```
show grants;
```

You'll probably see something like
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'**localhost**'