# Base table or view not found - symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have problem with deploying of symfony2 app. I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '14271425_sjokh.Books' doesn't exist
```

I have found out that this error is connected with case issue.

The given table exists on server but is called `books` not `Books`.

I have tried to solved this by modyfing config.yml, adding to it  `naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore` (as proposed here: [Symfony2: Base table or view not found: 1146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380154/symfony2-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146)) but it did not helped.

```
doctrine:

    orm:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine underscore naming strategy doesn't pluralize entity names, like it's case in RoR for example.

So, for **Book** entity, underscore strategy expects table named **book**. For **SomeCamelcase** entity, it expects **some_camelcase** table.

You should either rename your table or tell doctrine what table name is through config. If using annotations for example, it will be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="books")
 */
class Book
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem was connected with wrong cases in doctrine annotations.

I have deleted the following code:

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="Books")
```

and this together with edit of config file adding:

```
doctrine:

    orm:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

made the script working.