# Doctrine parameter to create lower-case tables?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mapping, case-insensitive

Doctrine creates tables with names similar to the entities, using the same case.
The problem is, of course, that some systems or environements have different settings, which may lead to issues between dev / stage / prod.

While we have already put `lower_case_table_names=1` on our database, and changed every table mapping manually so that it is not sensitive, this isn't very handy.

- Having to set it for every table can be heavy.
- From a maintenance perspective, this creates not only more work, but also more risks of mistakes when creating new tables
- Having to set the DB param on MySQL side is not heavy work, but may always add unneeded complications

So here's my question :

**is there no existing way to just ask Doctrine to create tables in lower-case ?**

What seems quite weird to me is that (from what I know), the standarts are to have entities/classes starting with a Capital, while databases table names should be only lower_case.

So I was expecting that the default behaviour would create lower-case tables, or at least, that a simple boolean Doctrine parameter could enable that.

We use Symfony2.
Here's the mapping used for our tables (found in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380154/symfony2-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146/14380257#14380257))

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="something")
 */
class Something {
    [...]
}
```

I also read about the `underscore naming strategy`, but replacing camel case with underscores doesn't imply it will also remove the starting capital, does it ?
(I'm not dev on the project, so I couldn't try it)

Comment: The underscore naming strategy lets you specify the case: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html#underscore-naming-strategy

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the link.  I didn't found precise info about this.  I guess you could make this an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set preferable naming strategy: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/namingstrategy.html#underscore-naming-strategy

In config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

Comment: Link is 404 now

Comment: @James, I've updated the URL. 